# Filter object by key array

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I have an object that looks like this:

```
tagCount = {key1: val1, key2: val2...keyn:valn}
```

And an array that looks like this:

```
keys = ['key1', 'key3', 'key5'];
```

I want to get an object (or an array I guess) from tagCount with only the fields that match keys:

```
foo - {key1: val1, key3: val3, key5: val5}
```

I use Underscore so I feel like this is possible but for the life of me I cannot figure out the magic to make it happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you want [_.pick](http://underscorejs.org/#pick)

Should be something like this:
`_.pick(tagCount, keys)`

Comment: Not sure pick is right? It takes away the properties, not the whole record?

Comment: No _.pick returns a new object containing a filtered set of key-value pairs. See the _.pick documentation I linked for an example.

If you only want the values, you would also need to call _.values:
http://underscorejs.org/#values

Comment: you are right, that's not how I read the documentation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

not using underscore...

```
var result = [];
for (var i in keys; i<keys.length; i++){
  if (tagCount.hasOwnProperty(keys[i])){
    result.push(tagCount[keys[i]]);
  }
}
console.log(result)
```

I think it should work...

Comment: Thanks, my answer is similar.